# Jenkins simple theme plugin examples or tutorial

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I installed the Simple Theme plugin on my Jenkins instance, and I managed to do some (very) basic theme changes.

Does anyone have a better reference to the Jenkins theme?

The [plugin page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Simple+Theme+Plugin) is very low on info...

If I want to override a style attribute, I have to dig into the generated html and do a lot of experimenting.

Comment: >If I want to override a style attribute, I have to dig into the generated html and do a lot of experimenting.

Sounds familiar :) How much documentation/information is available depends first and foremost on the develper(s) who wrote the plugin, and, secondly, on the plugin popularity. This one does not look particularly popular.

Comment: Besides - how much documentation you want on what - HTML? CSS? Jenkins generates HTML, so you can use Chrome or Firefox with FireBug to inspect both HTML and corresponding styles. Although Jenkins is using quite a strict HTML those pages might change anyway as result of installing plugins, etc. So how much documentation is enough? For me the published docs are just right.

Comment: I am looking for documentation on the Jenkins UI. NOT the plugin (if it's not clear - I'll edit the question). I was hoping for a more constructive comment...

Comment: I hope you will find more time to improve Jenkins theme and maybe even change the default theme, as I find it really ugly, especially the background image. It would be great to see a jenkins that is clean and accesible.

Answer (score 2):

You can customize your known simple theme with .css file.
Make sure that you have .png logo image, I have added 'Jenkins_home/usercontent/mytheme.css' file 'Jenkins_home/usercontent/logo.png' as my logo.
and follow the css below:

```css
@charset “utf-8”;
    #header .logo { 
        height: 36px;
    } 
    /* Custom style for my Jenkins Platform */
    .logo {
        background: url(/userContent/logo.png) no-repeat 10px center; 
    }

    .logo img { 
        display: none; 
    }

    .logo:after {
        content: 'Jenkins my instance';
        font-weight: bold;
        white-space: nowrap;
    } // Content after logo
```

Just check in Jenkins Configuration theme must be CSS URL and you must add path of above 'mytheme.css' file.
& Refresh your Jenkins Page.

Answer (score 1):

Found a simple tutorial here for start:

http://www.techgaun.com/2013/06/customizing-jenkins-layout.html

Answer (score 0):

Open Jenkins in Chrome or FireFox and press F12.
Right click on the UI element you want to change and select Inspect Element.
In the debug window the line in the html is highlighted.
Record the id and/or class of the UI element.
Open style.css and search for the id/class.
Copy the css-code and paste it in .css which you save in the css directory.
In the Theme section on the Configuration page enter css/.css as URL of theme CSS.
Now start altering .css to get the looks you desire.
Enable auto refesh to see the changes, Ctrl-F5 also helps

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP wants documentation on the theme, not how to get it.

Comment: The answer is not relevant to the Topic.